# optimize connections to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i have a php site
in index file include connect to db function :

```
function connect(){
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database");
}
```

and i use this function in everywhere i need connection

for example:

```
<?php
connect();
$lastnews_sql = mysql_query("SELECT text,time FROM small WHERE active='0' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10");
if(mysql_num_rows($lastnews_sql)) {
    while($Result123 = mysql_fetch_object($lastnews_sql)) {
?>
```

and use this selection:
    text; ?>

in end of using :

```
<?php
}
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

there are more than 10 connect(); and mysql_close(); in index file

so there are too many connection error in index file

how can i optimize this metod ?

Comment: create a singleton object/ or a registry pattern and store the connection there. and read when needed

Comment: Read more on this here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171300/db-object-passing-between-classes-singleton-static-or-other

Comment: Stop using `mysql`-functions, they will be deprecated soon! Use `mysqli` or PDO instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A singleton pattern seems to suit this down to the ground.

```
class Database
{
    private static $instance;

    public function getInstance()
    {
         if(self::$instance == null)
         {
            // Create a connection to the database.
            // NOTE: Use PDO or mysqli. mysql is deprecated.
         }
         return self::$instance; 
    }
}
```

**Use**

In your classes, instead of calling `connect`, assuming you're using a `PDO` object, you could do something like:

```
$db = Database::getInstance();
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tblName WHERE val = :val");
$statement->bindParam(":val", $value);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
```

**Why this pattern ?**

A Singleton pattern has the advantage of only having one instance of itself exist at one time. That means that you will only ever create one connection to the database.

**Setting this up**

Okay, so the first thing you want to do is to make a new file, let's call it `Database.php`. Inside `Database.php`, you want to pretty much write the code that I've written, only do **NOT** use `mysql_*`. Have a look at the `PDO` tutorial that I have provided, on how to connect to a database using a `PDO` object, and then you put that connection code inside the `if statement`, so it might look something like:

```
     if(self::$instance == null)
     {
        self::$instance = new PDO('mssql:host=sqlserver;dbname=database', 'username', 'password');
     }
```

Then, to use it in another class, put a `require` statement at the top. Something like:

```
require_once('Database.php');
```

Finally, look at the code I put in the `use` section, above. That is how you use it in your class.

**Useful links**

*PDO Tutorial* : http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php 
*Singleton Pattern* : http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html

Comment: i am beginner
can you describe and say me how can i replace this code with my example code i write in question?

Comment: thank you , can you replace select code with my code and val
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tblName WHERE val = :val");
$statement->bindParam(":val", $value);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
and echo value